# Invalid literal for int(string, base=16) despite type of input is seemingly correct

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote this function:

```
def hexToBinary(text):
    print type(text), text, int("b", base=16), int("B", base=16) # Added this line for debugging
    return '{:0{}b}'.format(int(text, base=16), len(text) * 4)
```

The function returns this:

```
<type 'str'> B 11 11
... Some Traceback
File "set1challenge6.py", line 41, in hexToBinary
return '{:0{}b}'.format(int(text, base=16), len(text) * 4)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\x1dB'
```

Given that `text` is a string and contains `"B"` why does `int("B", base=16)` return 11 and `int(text, base=16)` return an error?

What is the most likely mistake I should be looking for?

The function itself should be correct as I already used it to solve a couple of programming problems. I think something might be in the text variable, but other than verifying that it's the right type I don't know what to do.

Comment: what do you get for `len(text)`?

Comment: len appears to be 2. There must be a space I missed :P

Comment: i tried to rstrip(" ") the space but length is still 2..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra embedded character in your text which has hex value `1D`.  To remove it try this:

#### Code:

```
import string

def filter_out_junk(text):
    return ''.join(x for x in text if x in set(string.printable))
```

This will remove anything which is not considered [printable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.printable).

#### Test Code:

```
junk_string = '\x1dB'
print(int(filter_out_junk(junk_string), 16))
print(int(junk_string, 16))
```

#### Results:

```
11

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\x1dB'
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
from Crypto.Util.number import *

data = '\x1dB'
bytes_to_long(data)
```